# Can't change the concurrent compile operation in XCode 6.1

Tags: c++, xcode

I'm using the XCode version 6.1. And I use distcc to compile my C++ project.
When change the concurrent compile tasks setting by defaults command. They did not work. It always use 4 concurrent compile tasks.
The command I use:

```
defaults write com.apple.dt.Xcode  IDEBuildOperationMaxNumberOfConcurrentCompileTasks 8
```

Is anyone know how can I change this setting?